# What are the Stardew Valley IDs for Void Salmon, Void Essence, and Galaxy Soul?

Tags: stardew-valley

I've been playing Stardew Valley for a while, I've searched some websites, but I can't find the following IDs:

- Void Salmon
- Void Essence
- Galaxy Soul

Also, what is the Galaxy Soul's value?

Comment: Install SMAPI and run `list_items` in the console.

Answer (score 1):

- 305 Void Egg
- 308 Void Mayonnaise
- 769 Void Essence
- 795 Void Salmon
- 896 Galaxy Soul (Item Value = 5.000)

There are many more, although the list is very long, if you want to review any other look [here](https://www.mejoress.com/en/stardew-valley-item-id-item-codes-full-list/)